# django "Manager isn't accessible via User instance"

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I am having a reg form which saves the users firstname and lastname into auth_user table.

After login i am having a edit page which allow user to edit their firstname and lastname which should be saved(overwritten) to auth_user table in the respective user_id

When i try to do this, i am getting error as **"Manager isn't accessible via User instance"**

```
def editresume(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
      fname = request.POST.get('fname')
      lastname  = request.POST.get('lastname')
      User = request.user
      edit1 = User.objects.get(user_id=user)
      edit1.fname =fname
      edit1.lastname = lastname
      edit1.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/Profile/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('registration/personal_information.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Help me to fix this issue..! Thanks.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in these lines

```
User = request.user
edit1 = User.objects.get(user_id=user)
```

Probably you mistakenly defined variable `User` (with uppercase 'U') and you should be checking against `id` not `user_id`.

You would want to change it to

```
user = request.user
edit1 = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
```

or better don't define directly use `request.user`

```
edit1 = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

Or even better don't fetch from DB, you can directly use object in `request.user`

```
edit1 = request.user
```

Comment: s i did a mistake, but when i tried like this "edit1 = User.objects.get(user_id=request.user)" i am getting the following error "FieldError at /accounts/EditResume/

Cannot resolve keyword 'user_id' into field. Choices are: companyname, date_joined, email, emailaddress, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, js_details, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, profile, registrationprofile, socialaccount, user_permissions, username, usertype"

Comment: @USER, I overlooked it, `user_id` should be just `id` and similarly check for `request.user.id` not `request.user`. Check the updated answer. You may not need to get from DB.